# Normalization with respect to Dedekind domains.

Tags: reference-request, commutative-algebra

Let $R$ be a Dedekind domain. If $S$ is a finitely generated $R$-algebra that contains $R$, then there exists an element $r\in R$, such that $S_r$ is integral over a polynomial algebra over $R_r$.

This is very similar to the Noetherian normalization, does anyone know where I can find the proof of this normalization theorem?

Comment: Hochster proves it here for domains:
http://www.math.lsa.umich.edu/~hochster/615W10/supNoeth.pdf